# Codeigniter 4 auto routes cannot be redirected to?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes, authorization

I've set up a new CI4 project, set up CI4's Shield authorization library, and am literally starting from a fresh install. I've set up Auto Routing and created new Controllers (Dashboard.php, Profile.php, Login.php). I've also set up Filters to lock the Dashboard and Profile behind authentication, so it should redirect away to the login page.

My issue is Auto Routing knows there's a "Login" route, but when I try to access the Dashboard without being signed in, CI4 tells me **"The route for "login" cannot be found."**

Spark lists the Routes as follows:

```
+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------+
| Method     | Route           | Handler                                  | Before Filters     | After Filters |
+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------+
| GET        | /               | \App\Controllers\Home::getIndex          | session            | toolbar       |
| CLI        | ci(.*)          | \CodeIgniter\CLI\CommandRunner::index/$1 |                    |               |
| GET(auto)  | dashboard       | \App\Controllers\Dashboard::getIndex     | session            | toolbar       |
| GET(auto)  | login           | \App\Controllers\Login::getIndex         | auth-rates         | toolbar       |
| POST(auto) | login           | \App\Controllers\Login::postIndex        | auth-rates         | toolbar       |
| GET(auto)  | profile         | \App\Controllers\Profile::getIndex       | session auth-rates | toolbar       |
| GET(auto)  | results         | \App\Controllers\Results::getIndex       | session            | toolbar       |
| GET(auto)  | users           | \App\Controllers\Users::getIndex         | session            | toolbar       |
| GET(auto)  | users/edit[/..] | \App\Controllers\Users::getEdit          | session auth-rates | toolbar       |
| GET(auto)  | users/add       | \App\Controllers\Users::getAdd           | session auth-rates | toolbar       |
| GET(auto)  | work            | \App\Controllers\Work::getIndex          | session            | toolbar       |
```

Shield attempts to redirect to the "login" route in `/codeigniter4/shield/src/Filters/SessionAuth.php : 60`:

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

But it doesn't seem to recognize the Auto Route. I've verified the actual Auto Route **/login** does work and displays the view's contents.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that Auto routes cannot be redirected to?

I would HOPE that considering Shield is CI4's built in authorization system it would be able to redirect to a Login auto route...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you can't go to the default **login**(Shield) page. You can edit the file `app/Config/Routes.php`:

```
// service('auth')->routes($routes);
service('auth')->routes($routes, ['except' => ['login']]);
```

If your problem is not resolved, you can follow up with more details and providing the minimum code in Github [discussions](https://github.com/codeigniter4/shield/discussions/categories/q-a).

Comment: Thank you @datamweb for the suggestion. 

I had a fresh composer install of CodeIgniter 4 and Shield library.  The `app/Config/Routes.php`  file never contained anything with Auth service, just: `$routes->get('url', '(Controller)::(function)');`.

Autorouting was on, Shield was configured and blocked other pages (Login was excluded, no recursive redirect).

**The actual Login Route worked** and showed up if you accessed it directly, but for whatever reason when Shield redirected to the Login Route to authenticate, it 404'd.

I ended up turning off Autoroute, and added Login manually.

Comment: Found something here: https://github.com/codeigniter4/shield/discussions/538  --- Apparently, despite properly setting up Shield with `php spark shield::setup`, the `app/Config/Routes.php` wasn't properly edited with the Auth service you mentioned. It seems to have been a bug which this user also had.... and you helped them with. :)  Your answer is technically correct, so I will mark it as such. Thank you again.